# Does c++ standard specify how to pass this pointer to member functions?

Tags: c++

Most everybody knows that class member receive the **this** pointer as the first "invisible" parameter of the function.
Is this specified in C++ standard? Can a certain compiler implementation pass it in a different way? Dedicated registry for example.

Comment: The standard knows nothing about registeres - those are irrelevant implementation details. The standard only specifies which observable side effects a conforming program must produce. The implementation can do whatever it pleases to achieve those side effects. See also: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if

Comment: How arguments (including the implied `this` argument) are passed is a question for a given platform ABI, not the language standard. In modern ABIs, most arguments are passed in CPU registers.

Comment: The calling convention would surely dictate this. And this can be explicitly specified so the compiler will I would have thought default to `cdecl` or use the one specified?

Comment: @lfgtm *"The calling convention ... can be explicitly specified"* The C++ standard doesn't provide any way to do so, nor does it ever mention the term "calling convention". Any such mechanism is necessarily implementation-specific.

Comment: *"Can a certain compiler implementation pass it in a different way? Dedicated registry for example."* MSVC's [`__thiscall` calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx) does just that - `this` is passed in ECX register, the rest of the arguments goes onto the stack.

Answer (score 4):

That's certainly how the very first versions of C++ were implemented (early C++ was transformed into C code), but be assured that the C++ standard does **not** mandate this.

Passing it as the last parameter value also seems feasible, and for virtual functions, some different technique altogether.

Comment: Does anyone know of a compiler that *doesn't* pass `this` as the first parameter?

Comment: @AndyG MSVC. [`__thiscall` calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx) passes `this` on ECX register, while arguments go on the stack.

Comment: `virtual` functions, at least on some compilers (such as MSVC), sometimes use an adjustor thunk to assist with calling specific versions.  If classes `A`, `B`, and `C` define `virtual void func()`, and derived class `ABC : public A, public B, public C` overrides `func()`, MSVC will generate two thunks: one to adjust `ABC`'s `this` pointer's address when `ABC::B::func()` is called, and one to adjust it when `ABC::C::func()` is called.  (In my tests, `A` won't get one, because `A` begins at byte 0 of `ABC`, and thus any instance's `ABC* this` and its `A* this` point to the same address.)

Comment: Of course, that issue only comes up if you inherit from multiple base classes, two or more of which define a virtual function with the same signature, and that same function is then overridden by the derived class.  But still, it's one of the techniques compilers use when handling `this` and virtual functions.